# How can I set the width of a column in my table?

Tags: html, css

I am trying the following:

```
<th style="white-space: normal; width: 150rem;">Objective</th>
```

But it seems to completely ignore the width and when I check in Google Crome developer tools it says the width is 771 px. Note that 1rem = 10px with my font-size.

Comment: Make sure you are using `table-layout: fixed`; or set the `min-width`.

Comment: So you really want it `1,500px` wide?

Answer (score 0):

You don't want rem. You mean "em". There is no such measurement unit "rem":

```
<th style="white-space: normal; width: 150em;">Objective</th>
```

[Available measurement units](http://www.htmlref.com/reference/appb/measurements.htm): %, cm, em, ex, in, mm, pc, pt, px

Comment: Why should I not use rem ?

Comment: Unless of course you are exposing the table to [radiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roentgen_equivalent_man)

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your comments. Does the rem unit not work inside tables?

Comment: because rem is not a unit in HTML. em is a unit. Change rem to em. That will fix your problem. Please don't downvote me for giving you the answer.

Comment: @DerFlatulator actually [rem is a font size unit](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/font-size-with-rem) added in CSS3

Comment: An `em` is the width of the `m` character, a `rem` is an old unit for measuring radiation exposure.

Comment: @koala_dev ...lol. Okay, I guess I wasn't aware of that, but given that it's some fairly recent addition my guess is that's at least part of the problem here. God knows what the rest of the problem is.

Comment: Josh / Der - rem is a valid CSS measurement unit. We have been using it at our company for many web sites.

Comment: @Melina - it may be that the browser you're testing in does not recognize "rem" as a unit. This is probably the case. If anything it's a very recent addition to CSS3 and wouldn't be recognized by any version of IE, for example.

Comment: @joshstrike Apparently it's pretty well supported. ["Safari 5, Chrome, Firefox 3.6+, and even Internet Explorer 9"](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/font-size-with-rem)

Comment: Great. Did you test her code? Because I didn't but I'm pretty sure it'll break most browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain that `150rem` is the size you want? That equates to `1500px` almost the entire width of a Full HD monitor/screen, and way too wide for any feasible web application that comes to mind.

Check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bjdk9/) and note that the second table is only as wide as the `<body>` even though it has been specified a width of `150rem`. (Resize the width of the output panel). Chances are there is something in your DOM that is limiting the width of the `<tr>` to *only* `771px`.